# Create a field linked to a vocabulary with Drush

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, drush

Let's say I have created a taxonomy vocabulary called `ABC`.
For this vocabulary `ABC`, i want to create many fields using Drush.

I've tried

```
drush field-create ABC myfield,text,text_textfield
```

It works, doesn't give any error, but if I go to the admin panel, I click on `structure => taxonomy` then in the list I see `ABC`, I click on "`Edit`" then I click on the tab "`Manage fields`" where I **expect** to see my field. Because (correct me if I'm wrong) I think that the drush command line `field-create ABC myfield` should have added it. But no.

It's not there. But if I click on the combo of the "`Add existing field`" option, in the list, there's the `myfield` that I've just created!

It seems there "link" between `ABC` and `myfield` is not created. `myfield` is  created, but it's not "included" in the `ABC` fields.

Am I doing something wrong, or missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing Entity type. See the [documentation](http://drush.ws/#field-create) from drush

> Create fields and instances. Returns urls for field editing.
>
> Examples:  drush field-create article                Define new
>   article fields via interactive prompts.                        open
>   `drush field-create article`         Define new article fields and
>   then open field edit form for refinement.   drush field-create article
>   Create two new fields.
>   city,text,text_textfield
>   subtitle,text,text_textfield
>
> Arguments:  bundle                                    Content type
>   (for nodes). Name of bundle to attach fields to. Required.
>   field_spec                                Comma delimited triple in
>   the form: field_name,field_type,widget_name. If widget_name is
>   omitted, the default widget 
>                                              will be used. Separate multiple fields by space. If omitted, a wizard will prompt you.
>
> Options:  --entity_type                             Type of entity
>   (e.g. node, user, comment). **Defaults to node.**

As you can see the entity type defaults to node . So you have to specify the entity type as taxonomy_term.

> drush field-create ABC myfield,text,text_textfield --entity_type=taxonomy_term

Comment: Do you know how to get a list of all availaible `entity_type`?

Comment: entity_get_info($entity_type = NULL) can do it.